# How to fetch the list of dynamic ID one at a time by applying ID as a parameter in GET URL of API testing using karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to fetch the list of dynamic id's one at a time by application ID as a parameter in GET URL

Example : below response is for POST call
{"Car": 1,
content:[{
"type" : "A"
"Id" : "1"
},
{
"type" : "B"
"Id" : "2"
}
]}

Now for the above POST response I am trying to fetch the data using dynamic Id as a parameter in GET URL
ex:

- def ID = karate.jsonPath(response, '$.content[*].id')
  Given URL  'https://localhost:8080'
  And path '/'+ID+'/id
  When method GET
  Then status 200

in GET response I am getting list of Id's instead of single Id in URL as shown below
This is the output : http://localhost:8080/1,2/id

As Id's are generating dynamically, so instead of calling one by one ID manually I want to call using parameter
Can any one suggest me how can I fetch one ID at a time using GET URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example, and observe the output and then try to understand how it works:

```
* def response = {"Car": 1, content:[{ "type" : "A", "Id" : "1" }, { "type" : "B", "Id" : "2" } ]}
* def ids = $response.content[*].Id
* match ids == ['1', '2']
* def data = karate.mapWithKey(ids, 'id')
* call read('called.feature') data
```

And `called.feature` looks like this:

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* param id = id
* method get
```

Please try to read the docs, it is worth it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms