# Using (null) still omits the key in the actual GET call, need to find a way to send a null value

Tags: karate

I have the following setup:

```
* table requestTable
   | q      | um | ie  | status |
   | (null) | 1  | utf | 400    |
* call read('called.feature') requestTable
```

And `called.feature` looks like this:

```
* def requiredParams = { q: '#(q)', um: '#(um)', ie: '#(ie)'}

url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
params requiredParams
method GET
```

The call does fail. However, not for the reason I want. The "q" key is removed from the actual GET call. I need it to go through like: "q=" in the actual request. So the request should look like:
`https://httpbin.org/anything/q=&um=1&ie=utf`

Please advise.

Comment: congratulations ! finally you asked a question close to an ideal state. I anyway re-did it so you can see the few more improvements you can make. was that so hard ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Take some time to understand the difference between strings in a `table` - they have to be variables or within quotes (just like JS).

The solution you missed is that you need an empty string, not `null` - which would remove the entire `param` from the request.

```
Feature:

Scenario:
* table requestTable
 | q  | um | ie    | status |
 | '' | 1  | 'utf' | 400    |
* call read('called.feature') requestTable
```

And `called.feature` is:

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
* def requiredParams = { q: '#(q)', um: '#(um)', ie: '#(ie)' }
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* params requiredParams
* method get
```

The request made is:

```
1 > GET https://httpbin.org/anything?q=&um=1&ie=utf
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.11)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Comment: So null and an empty string are interchangeably in this case? I had found this in research and my Team Lead was saying sending a null value is different. However, I think he is wrong. Thank you for confirming this!

Comment: @hungryhippos I edited my answer a little more. yes your team lead seems to be confused