# Karate - Unable to get a list of 2 lists elements from a response

Tags: arrays, karate, jsonpath

I'm struggling with this for several days.
This is the answer I get (with anonymous data).
I want to retrieve the first "channel_definitions[2]" by checking this data :

When the channel_definitions is an array of 2 then :

- the name is "Maddy's life ***********" for the mode "THE FIRST MODE" (please note there is a " ' " in the name)
- the name is  " *********** computer" for the mode "THE SECOND MODE"
  [
  {
  "id": "82",
  "channel_definitions": [
  {
  "id": "8200",
  "mode": "THE FIRST MODE",
  "types": [
  "VALUE",
  "HOME"
  ],
  "interactive": true,
  "name": "Maddy's life ***********",
  },
  {
  "id": "8201",
  "mode": "THE SECOND MODE",
  "types": [
  "BOOKING",
  "CREDIT"
  ],
  "name": " *********** computer"
  }
  ]
  },
  {
  "id": "10002",
  "channel_definitions": [
  {
  "id": "1000201",
  "mode": "THE SECOND MODE",
  "types": [
  "BOOKING",
  "CREDIT"
  ],
  "name": " *********** computer"
  }
  ]
  },
  {
  "id": "88",
  "channel_definitions": [
  {
  "id": "8800",
  "mode": "THE FIRST MODE",
  "types": [
  "BOOKING",
  "VALUE",
  "HOME",
  "CREDIT"
  ],
  "name": "piano §§§§§§§§§§"
  }
  ]
  },
  {
  "id": "149",
  "channel_definitions": [
  {
  "id": "14900",
  "mode": "THE FIRST MODE",
  "types": [
  "VALUE"
  ],
  "name": "+++++ paraglading ++++++++++++++"
  }
  ]
  },
  ]

I have done the 2 others parts.

I tried everything I thought can works and I read on the Internet but not the correct one.
For instance deals with these ideas

- def listOfChannelDef = karate.jsonPath(response, "$..channel_definitions== '#[2]'")
- def listOfChannelDef = karate.jsonPath(response, "$..channel_definitions[2]")

Please if you know how to do it or has any idea of how to do it let me know.

Alicya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not using JsonPath and instead - using simple JS functions (built-in to arrays) to get what you want.

For example, this is the best guess of your question:

```
* def found = response.find(x => x.channel_definitions.length == 2 && x.channel_definitions[0].mode == 'THE FIRST MODE' && x.channel_definitions[0].name == "Maddy's life ***********")
```

If you want to make it easier to read:

```
* def fun = 
"""
function(x) {
  return x.channel_definitions.length == 2 
    && x.channel_definitions[0].mode == 'THE FIRST MODE' 
    && x.channel_definitions[0].name == "Maddy's life ***********";
}
"""
* def found = response.find(fun)
```

All JSON arrays in Karate are ["true" JS arrays](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms), so the functions [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can be applied very effectively to do JSON transforms.

For example, if you just want to "collect" all `channel_definitions` that have a length of 2 as a first step, and then do some checks. And note how you can escape the single-quote or you could have used double-quotes also like shown above.

```
* def filtered = response.filter(x => x.channel_definitions.length == 2)
* def names = filtered[0].channel_definitions.map(x => x.name)
* match names == ['Maddy\'s life ***********', ' *********** computer']
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't know how to simply explain my question because this is not clear in my mind too.. thank you so much for your help