# How can I print two values, id and name, together from an array of JSON objects in Karate?

Tags: karate

How to print  two values from the response (array of JSON objects)

I have a test in Karate where the response is an array of JSON objects, all of them include a key called id. and name. I need to print only id -> name from the entire response

I can print a single values like this

- def id = $response.data[*].id
- def name = $response.data[*].name

But not sure how to print both values together

I can print a single values like this

- def id = $response.data[*].id
- def name = $response.data[*].name

But not sure how to print both values together like

1 - John
2 - David
3 - Tom

Answer (score 0):

It is better to just loop over the array. Note that `print` also gives you the option to have multiple arguments like `karate.log()` below:

```
* response.data.forEach(x => karate.log('id:', x.id, 'name:', x.name)
```

You should be using Karate to do assertions, not `print` :)

Another way to approach the problem is to create a new array:

```
* def temp = response.data.map(x => `${x.id} - ${x.name}`)
* print temp
```

Refer this answer to understand how the above "loops" work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475