# how to push the json objects to array using karate object

Tags: karate

Question is related to adding json objects to array using karate API
Below is my code.

```
    * def appendBasics =
    """
    function() {
    var group = {}
group['details'] = group['details'] || []
     karate.append(group['details'], { b: 2 })
     karate.append(group['details'], { b: 4 })
     karate.log(group)
    }
    """
    * def bar = appendBasics()
    * print bar
```

Output which I am expecting is

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "b": "2"
    },
    {
      "b": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output which I am getting is

```
{
  "details": [
  ]
}
```

Could you please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use native array operations. The use of `karate.append()` etc and even `karate.map()` is not needed any more. I revised your code below:

```
* def appendBasics =
"""
function() {
  var group = {}
  group['details'] = group['details'] || []
  group['details'].push({ b: 2 });
  group['details'].push({ b: 4 });
  return group;
}
"""
* def bar = appendBasics()
* print bar
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475