# How to match the string in the response array

Tags: karate

I am trying to compare a string (mailId) with the array of response data and get the corresponding Id to pass to the next request.Response:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 93,
    "sender": "<info@xxx.xx>",
    "recipients": [
      "<xakaeddrkjyf@gmail.com>"
    ],
    "subject": "Update Your Account",
    "size": "49351",
    "created_at": "2023-12-27T08:47:40+00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 94,
    "sender": "<info@xxx.xx>",
    "recipients": [
      "<ywjhmstfyihw@gmail.com>"
    ],
    "subject": "Update Your Account",
    "size": "49351",
    "created_at": "2023-12-27T08:49:34+00:00"
  }
]
```

And my code snippet is

```js
 * def getvalidId =
  """
  function(response){
    for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
        if (response[i].subject === "Update Your Account"){
         if((response[i].recipients).indexOf(3,25) === "ywjhmstfyihw@gmail.com")
          {
            return response[i].id
            }
        }
    }
```

JavaScript functions related to match, substring, indexof are working fine and issue is seen only in Karate.

Comment: sorry this is absolutely not the way karate is supposed to be used. read my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475 - it is possible to do the match you want without any JS, refer to the docs for more

Answer (score 0):

These 3 lines are sufficient for your use case:

```
* def fun = x => x.subject == 'Update Your Account' && x.recipients[0] == 'ywjhmstfyihw@gmail.com'
* def found = response.find(fun)
* def id = found.id
```

To understand how this works if needed, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter Thomas. It worked seamlessly.