# Karate : how to get an object from a Json array by checking one of its field

Tags: karate

We are testing an API that returns a body that looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "abc" : "abc",
    "bcd" : "bcd",
    "moduleList": [
      {
        "certificate": {
          "code": "P",
          "idAES": 739296
        },
        "date": "2024-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
        "idModule": 12345,
        "moduleNumero": 1
      },
      {
        "certificate": {
          "codee": "P",
          "idAES": 9
        },
        "date": "2024-02-08T00:00:00+01:00",
        "idModule": 98729,
        "moduleNumero": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2024-05-05T00:00:00+02:00",
        "idModule": 109364,
        "moduleNumero": 3
      }
    ],
    "cde": "cde"
  }
]
```

We have 3 objects in the moduleList. We know that the object that has *"moduleNumero":1* should have a *"certificate"* object inside itself, as well as the object that has *"moduleNumero":2* .

The object that has *"moduleNumero":3* should not have it.

The problem is that the API doesn't return these objects in this specific order every time, so we can't check by doing "*And assert response[0].moduleList[0].certificate == '#present'* " because the first in the list could be any of these.

Is there a way to define a variable on the  json object that contains *"moduleNumero":1* (or 2) so we can then check that the object "certificate" is present in it ?

Is there another way to achieve this assertion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `response` is only the `moduleList` array from your example:

```
* def modulesWithCert = response.filter(x => x.certificate)
```

This will get you only the ones with a certificate. I personally prefer this approach instead of JsonPath `[*]` or filters because it is more readable.

Refer to other ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475

Comment: It's working well ! Thanks for your help Peter !

Answer (score 2):

```
 * match response[*].moduleList[*].certificate == '#present'
```