How to loop through a JSON array and match the length of the keys in each object using Karate
I have a JSON array that looks something like this -
{ “products”: [ { “code”: “abc”, “name”: “test” }, { “code”: “abc2”, “name”: “test2” }, … ] }
I’d like to loop over the json array and check the length  using Karate. f the number of keys in each item. Using the example above, the length of the number of keys should be 2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I’ve tried just getting the keys by doing

def res = get $..products.[*]
print karate.keysOf(res)

However, it just returns null and doing karate.sizeOf returns the total size instead of the size of each item.

Personally I think you should be doing better assertions, like checking the keys and values. Refer this answer.
But anyway, this is how your question can be answered:
* def products = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {x: 1, y: 2}]
* def sizes = products.map(x => Object.keys(x).length)
* match each sizes == 2

For an explanation of map() refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475
And Object.keys() is a standard JS function, similar to karate.keysOf(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
