How to merge 2 JSON payloads using Karate
In my project, there is a requirement for me to get user_id from Endpoint 1,
Then merge with sessions data from endpoint 2.
Input 1:
    {_user_id: "user1"}

Input 2:
    {
    "_session_id": "5182d9fe-1f4f-484b-88c2-708f32cdd661"
    },
    {
    "_session_id": "372cf574-2526-41ed-9a9b-77ecc50b0d66"
    }

Expected output
    {
    "_user_id: "user1",
    "_session_id": "5182d9fe-1f4f-484b-88c2-708f32cdd661"
    },
    {
    "_user_id: "user1",
    "_session_id": "372cf574-2526-41ed-9a9b-77ecc50b0d66"
    }

Is there a way to achieve this in Karate?

I suggest you work with someone to learn the basics of manipulating JSON in JS. You can use this as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475
This can be just one line:
* def data = input2.map(x => { x._user_id = input1._user_id; return x })


Thank you Peter! sorry I am a noob in JS. A lot to learn!

Please use keyword set in Karate
Feature: Merge JSON Payloads from different end points

  Scenario: Merge JSON Payloads

    * def response1 =  { "_user_id": "user1" }
    * print response1

    * def response2 =
    """
    [
    {
    "_session_id": "5182d9fe-1f4f-484b-88c2-708f32cdd661"
    },
    {
    "_session_id": "372cf574-2526-41ed-9a9b-77ecc50b0d66"
    }
    ]
    """
    * print response2

    * set response2[0]._user_id = response1._user_id
    * set response2[1]._user_id = response1._user_id
    * print response2

Html report


Thank you for the prompted response! Yes this works too!
