How can I validate that a name-value pair has a value that contains text in an API response object?
I am currently writing API tests with karate and I've run into a scenario I've been struggling to resolve. I'd like to validate that each object within the response has a specific item that has a value that contains a substring.
For example, lets say that my response schema is the following:
[
  {
    "Name-1": "Value-1",
    "Name-2": "Value-2",
    "Name-3": "Value-3",
    "Name-4": "Value-4",
  }
]

I'd like to validate that each object has an item with the name "Name-2" that has a value that contains "2".
My current approach is the following:
* match each response[*].Name-2 contains "2"
which gives me a success. However, the schema has recently changed and some of the items I was previously validating are no longer present. Lets say this item is called "Old-Name-2": "Old-Value-2".
The validation is was using is similar to the above:
* match each response[*].Old-Name-2 contains "2"
The problem that I'm running into is that when I run my test with this line I'm getting a false positive result. I'd like the the test to error because Old-Name-2 is no longer in the response object.
The test appropriately errors when I add:
* match response[0].Old-Name-2 contains "2"
How can I iterate a response to validate name and that the value contains a certain string without the risk of getting false positives?

I would suggest a different approach. When faced with "dynamic keys", it is better to transform the input data into a form that's better suited to normal match assertions. Here's one way:
* def response = 
"""
{
    "Name-1": "Value-1",
    "Name-2": "Value-2",
    "Name-3": "Value-3",
    "Name-4": "Value-4"
}
"""
* def keys = karate.keysOf(response)
* def pairs = keys.map(x => ({ key: x, value: response[x] }))
* match pairs contains { key: 'Name-2', value: "#? _.includes('2')" }

You can build on this and do any other assertion easily.
For details on similar JSON transformations, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475
