Karate Xml Parsing
 <Batch>
    <results>
        <columns>
            <column index="0">Sample Batch ID</column>
            <column index="1">Status</column>
            <column index="2">GSA-48v4-0</column>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row index="0">
                <column index="0">102</column>
                <column index="1">Completed</column>
                <column index="2">GSA-48v4-0</column>
            </row>
            <row index="1">
                <column index="0">102</column>
                <column index="1">Active</column>
                <column index="2">GSA-48v4-0</column>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </results>
</Batch>

I have a xml format like this. I need to get the column value with index 0 of the nodes if its second column value is 'Active'. so here I need to get 102. It should return a list of all the nodes having column value as 'Active'.
Any help is appreciated.

This is actually harder than it looks, so I suggest converting to JSON to make it easier.
* json data = response
* def rows = data.Batch.results.rows.row.map(x => x._.column)
* def result = rows.find(x => x[1]._ == 'Active')
* assert result[0]._ == '102'

It may take time to get used to how Karate converts XML to JSON. The second line above focuses on the data you need. The find() function applies the rule you mentioned. Instead of find() maybe you should use filter() and expect the result to be a JSON array. Work with someone who knows JS well if needed.
For more details on the JS functions that allow you to do this, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475
